# JQuery SlidesJS iPad link fails with one slide

Tags: jquery, slidesjs

I know this is a specific device issue and appreciate not everyone will have an ipad to test with.

I have another problem with the SlidesJS 3.0.3 plugin.  If I have a single slide it displays ok on the ipad but when you click it, the slide goes blank and the link doesn't work.

http://blahblahdev.atwebpages.com/rotator-ipad.html

If there's more than one slide the link works fine.

EDIT
I have noticed that if you press the play button (using any browser) then the slide disappears - which may be the same issue as i have with ipad.

Comment: Why do you have a slider if you have only one slide in it? One workaround is to add the same slide twice if you need only one slide but want to keep the slider and not change it with an image container.

Comment: This is just a sample page, I'm using it on a cms site where pages on the rotator can expire leaving just one item.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to put a work around in place for ipads.  I've added an id to the anchors id="ni0".

```
<div class="slide">
    <a id="ni0" href="http://www.google.co.uk">
         <img src="img/rotator1.png" alt="Slide 1">
    </a>                        
    <p class="caption" style="bottom:0">
         <p>Rotator 1</p>
         <p>Rotator 1 text goes here.</p>
    </p>

</div>
```

I then check the length of slides is less than two.  I then manually get the href of the anchor id="ni0" and do the forwarding.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

 if($(".slide").length < 2 )
 {
    // Single slide fix for ipad
    // Manually forward tap to url of slide
    $('#slides').click(function(){ window.location = document.getElementById("ni0").href; }) 
 }      

});
```